# React Native Formatting User Address String

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I'm trying to format an address string in React Native.

The address string data given is `123 STREET, 123 CITY, PROVINCE 123`

and I want to show only `PROVINCE 123`

What should I do.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the address format is consistent, you could do this:

```
const address = "123 STREET, 123 CITY, PROVINCE 123"
const province = address.split(', ')[2]
```

the split function  `.split(', ')` turns the string into an array of substrings and use `', '` as the separator, which return an array like this

```
["123 STREET","123 CITY","PROVINCE 123"]
```

then just access the index of the province, you could do this if only the format is `consistent` (street and city must be provided or at least an empty string just to keep the format `street-name, city-name, province-name`)